# calling function from viewcontroller - parameters error - Swift2

Tags: swift, swift2

I am having trouble calling the tweet function. I keep getting errors with the parameters. I also tried just (AnyObject) and got 
Error: argument type does not conform to expected...

I am new to swift and not sure how to get this running. Tried everything I can think of. Thank you

```
   // from GameScene 
  var vc = ViewController()
  vc.tweetAction(sender: AnyObject)
  //error: cannot create single-element tuple with an element label



   //function in View Controller below

    @IBAction func tweetAction(sender: AnyObject){

    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter){

        let tweetController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)

        tweetController.setInitialText("I Scored on this app")

        self.presentViewController(tweetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please log into your twitter to share", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertACtion) in

            let settingsURL = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)

            if let url = settingsURL{

                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
            }
        }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a type to your method invocation instead of an instance.  You also are including a label for the first parameter, which is incorrect.  Try:

```
vc.tweetAction(self)
```

Comment: self seems to break the code when button is pressed. the line----------------> let skView = self.view as! SKView throws the error "Thread1 signal SIGARBT,

Comment: Error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" The line that breaks is `let skView = self.view as! SKView` where I configure the view. The console says 'Could not cast value of type UIVIew to SKView. The button is an SKSpriteNode if that makes any diffrence.

Comment: That implies that self.view is either nil or not an instance of SKView.  You should verify those things with the debugger.

Comment: What does that mean?  The error only occurs when I press the button.

Comment: I can't see that part of your code, so I can't speculate.  I would suggest you put a break point on that line and validate that self.view is in fact not nil and of type SKView.  Those are the things that would crash that line.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change sender parameter type from `AnyObject` to `UILabel`

```
 var vc = ViewController()
 vc.tweetAction(yourUILabelInstance)
```

And don't forget to modify tweetAction function as well

```
@IBAction func tweetAction(sender: UILabel){
...
}
```